# Flutter - Carousel slider, turn off sliding animation on appear for iOS

Tags: flutter

I am using carousel slider in flutter and when the screen appears slider card animates from left to right for ios only, it does not animate in android. Is there any way to remove this animation for ios?

```
return CarouselSlider(
  carouselController: _controller,
  options: CarouselOptions(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
    enableInfiniteScroll: false,
    viewportFraction: 1.0,
    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
      setState(() {
```

I am using

```
    _controller.animateToPage((2),
        duration: Duration(microseconds: 0));
```

to animate to the required page. I have tried using

```
    _controller.jumpToPage(2);
```

but still get the sliding animation from leading edge.

Comment: Could you add a gif or clip from its behavior? Maybe you should add `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()` somewhere in the slider since this property is different on Android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
enlargeCenterPage: false,
```